# Google Cloud: You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I am a verified domain owner for a domain that has been successfully mapped to my Google Cloud App Engine project, and functions at http://app.[mydomain].com.

When I go to upload an SSL certificate, I am getting the message "You are not an authorized owner of the domain for this certificate".

I am a verified domain owner, and this is a wildcard cert created in GoDaddy.

Comment: Look at the certificate CN and SAN fields. Do they match your domain name?

Comment: Yes, they do... I just found this documentation that recommends disabling the Google-managed certificates first:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl
...but thank you for your time.